# Tikz problem since TeXLive 2015 update

Tags: tikz-pgf, texlive, gnuplot

sorry if I do something wrong, it is my first post.
I generate usually pdfs with gnuplot by using the output terminal tkiz to generate first a .tex and afterwards a .pdf.
I recently updated to TeXLive. Now the compilation from .tex to .pdf does not work anymore.

My example is a .tex that was generate by the "set term tkiz" output in gnuplot.
I get the error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.22 \gpsetdashtype
                   {gp dt solid}
```

without being able to explain it.  Does somebody know how to fix it?
Thank you for looking into the problem.

Edit: Here is an example that runs now through in an empty folder. But I am not sure what this "createstyle" does. Usually I enter here "standalone header "\usepackage{MyGnuplotLaTeX}" that is a .sty file calling usepackages like siunitx for me.

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot 
basename='test_graph.plt'
end3='.tex'
f(x)=sin(x)
plot f(x) with lines #ls 1 
set term tikz size 342.435pt,228pt standalone create style font \\rmfamily,12pt"
set output basename.end3
replot
set output
system(sprintf('pdflatex %s%s', basename, end3))
```

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Standalone example to be compiled via pdflatex for example. %%%%

\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\usepackage{gnuplot-lua-tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{\gpbboxborder}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[gnuplot]
%% generated with GNUPLOT 5.0p1 (Lua 5.2; terminal rev. 99, script rev. 100)
%% Fri Sep 11 09:10:43 2015
\tikzset{every node/.append style={font={\rmfamily\fontsize{12pt}{14.4pt}\selectfont}}}
\path (0.000,0.000) rectangle (12.035,8.013);
\gpcolor{color=gp lt color border}
\gpsetlinetype{gp lt border}
\gpsetdashtype{gp dt solid}
\gpsetlinewidth{1.00}
\draw[gp path] (1.430,0.740)--(1.610,0.740);
\draw[gp path] (11.372,0.740)--(11.192,0.740);
\node[gp node right,font={\rmfamily\fontsize{12pt}{14.4pt}\selectfont}] at (1.210,0.740) {$-1$};
\draw[gp path] (1.430,1.423)--(1.610,1.423);
\draw[gp path] (11.372,1.423)--(11.192,1.423);
\node[gp node right,font={\rmfamily\fontsize{12pt}{14.4pt}\selectfont}] at (1.210,1.423) {$-0.8$};
\draw[gp path] (1.430,2.106)--(1.610,2.106);
\draw[gp path] (11.372,2.106)--(11.192,2.106);
\node[gp node right,font={\rmfamily\fontsize{12pt}{14.4pt}\selectfont}] at (1.210,2.106) {$-0.6$};
\draw[gp path] (1.430,2.789)--(1.610,2.789);
\draw[gp path] (11.372,2.789)--(11.192,2.789);
\node[gp node right,font={\rmfamily\fontsize{12pt}{14.4pt}\selectfont}] at (1.210,2.789) {$-0.4$};
\draw[gp path] (1.430,3.472)--(1.610,3.472);
\draw[gp path] (11.372,3.472)--(11.192,3.472);
\node[gp node right,font={\rmfamily\fontsize{12pt}{14.4pt}\selectfont}] at (1.210,3.472) {$-0.2$};
\draw[gp path] (1.430,4.155)--(1.610,4.155);
\draw[gp path] (11.372,4.155)--(11.192,4.155);
\node[gp node right,font={\rmfamily\fontsize{12pt}{14.4pt}\selectfont}] at (1.210,4.155) {$0$};
\draw[gp path] (1.430,4.838)--(1.610,4.838);
\draw[gp path] (11.372,4.838)--(11.192,4.838);
\node[gp node right,font={\rmfamily\fontsize{12pt}{14.4pt}\selectfont}] at (1.210,4.838) {$0.2$};
\draw[gp path] (1.430,5.521)--(1.610,5.521);
\draw[gp path] (11.372,5.521)--(11.192,5.521);
\node[gp node right,font={\rmfamily\fontsize{12pt}{14.4pt}\selectfont}] at (1.210,5.521) {$0.4$};
\draw[gp path] (1.430,6.204)--(1.610,6.204);
\draw[gp path] (11.372,6.204)--(11.192,6.204);
\node[gp node right,font={\rmfamily\fontsize{12pt}{14.4pt}\selectfont}] at (1.210,6.204) {$0.6$};
\draw[gp path] (1.430,6.887)--(1.610,6.887);
\draw[gp path] (11.372,6.887)--(11.192,6.887);
\node[gp node right,font={\rmfamily\fontsize{12pt}{14.4pt}\selectfont}] at (1.210,6.887) {$0.8$};
\draw[gp path] (1.430,7.570)--(1.610,7.570);
\draw[gp path] (11.372,7.570)--(11.192,7.570);
\node[gp node right,font={\rmfamily\fontsize{12pt}{14.4pt}\selectfont}] at (1.210,7.570) {$1$};
\draw[gp path] (1.430,0.740)--(1.430,0.920);
\draw[gp path] (1.430,7.570)--(1.430,7.390);
\node[gp node center,font={\rmfamily\fontsize{12pt}{14.4pt}\selectfont}] at (1.430,0.371) {$-10$};
\draw[gp path] (3.916,0.740)--(3.916,0.920);
\draw[gp path] (3.916,7.570)--(3.916,7.390);
\node[gp node center,font={\rmfamily\fontsize{12pt}{14.4pt}\selectfont}] at (3.916,0.371) {$-5$};
\draw[gp path] (6.401,0.740)--(6.401,0.920);
\draw[gp path] (6.401,7.570)--(6.401,7.390);
\node[gp node center,font={\rmfamily\fontsize{12pt}{14.4pt}\selectfont}] at (6.401,0.371) {$0$};
\draw[gp path] (8.887,0.740)--(8.887,0.920);
\draw[gp path] (8.887,7.570)--(8.887,7.390);
\node[gp node center,font={\rmfamily\fontsize{12pt}{14.4pt}\selectfont}] at (8.887,0.371) {$5$};
\draw[gp path] (11.372,0.740)--(11.372,0.920);
\draw[gp path] (11.372,7.570)--(11.372,7.390);
\node[gp node center,font={\rmfamily\fontsize{12pt}{14.4pt}\selectfont}] at (11.372,0.371) {$10$};
\draw[gp path] (1.430,7.570)--(1.430,0.740)--(11.372,0.740)--(11.372,7.570)--cycle;
\node[gp node right,font={\rmfamily\fontsize{12pt}{14.4pt}\selectfont}] at (9.652,7.205) {f(x)};
\gpcolor{rgb color={0.690,0.188,0.376}}
\gpsetlinewidth{2.00}
\draw[gp path] (9.872,7.205)--(10.932,7.205);
\draw[gp path] (1.430,6.013)--(1.530,5.400)--(1.631,4.737)--(1.731,4.050)--(1.832,3.367)%
  --(1.932,2.716)--(2.033,2.124)--(2.133,1.615)--(2.233,1.208)--(2.334,0.922)--(2.434,0.767)%
  --(2.535,0.750)--(2.635,0.871)--(2.736,1.126)--(2.836,1.504)--(2.936,1.990)--(3.037,2.564)%
  --(3.137,3.203)--(3.238,3.881)--(3.338,4.569)--(3.438,5.241)--(3.539,5.868)--(3.639,6.426)%
  --(3.740,6.892)--(3.840,7.246)--(3.941,7.474)--(4.041,7.568)--(4.141,7.523)--(4.242,7.340)%
  --(4.342,7.028)--(4.443,6.600)--(4.543,6.071)--(4.644,5.465)--(4.744,4.806)--(4.844,4.120)%
  --(4.945,3.435)--(5.045,2.780)--(5.146,2.181)--(5.246,1.662)--(5.347,1.244)--(5.447,0.945)%
  --(5.547,0.777)--(5.648,0.745)--(5.748,0.853)--(5.849,1.095)--(5.949,1.461)--(6.050,1.937)%
  --(6.150,2.503)--(6.250,3.136)--(6.351,3.811)--(6.451,4.499)--(6.552,5.174)--(6.652,5.807)%
  --(6.752,6.373)--(6.853,6.849)--(6.953,7.215)--(7.054,7.457)--(7.154,7.565)--(7.255,7.533)%
  --(7.355,7.365)--(7.455,7.066)--(7.556,6.648)--(7.656,6.129)--(7.757,5.530)--(7.857,4.875)%
  --(7.958,4.190)--(8.058,3.504)--(8.158,2.845)--(8.259,2.239)--(8.359,1.710)--(8.460,1.282)%
  --(8.560,0.970)--(8.661,0.787)--(8.761,0.742)--(8.861,0.836)--(8.962,1.064)--(9.062,1.418)%
  --(9.163,1.884)--(9.263,2.442)--(9.364,3.069)--(9.464,3.741)--(9.564,4.429)--(9.665,5.107)%
  --(9.765,5.746)--(9.866,6.320)--(9.966,6.806)--(10.066,7.184)--(10.167,7.439)--(10.267,7.560)%
  --(10.368,7.543)--(10.468,7.388)--(10.569,7.102)--(10.669,6.695)--(10.769,6.186)--(10.870,5.594)%
  --(10.970,4.943)--(11.071,4.260)--(11.171,3.573)--(11.272,2.910)--(11.372,2.297);
\gpcolor{color=gp lt color border}
\gpsetlinewidth{1.00}
\draw[gp path] (1.430,7.570)--(1.430,0.740)--(11.372,0.740)--(11.372,7.570)--cycle;
%% coordinates of the plot area
\gpdefrectangularnode{gp plot 1}{\pgfpoint{1.430cm}{0.740cm}}{\pgfpoint{11.372cm}{7.570cm}}
\end{tikzpicture}
%% gnuplot variables
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! You write two times "tkiz" but you mean Ti*k*Z, right? Could you please try to reduce your example as much as possible? E.g. I do not have `gnuplot-lua-tikz` on my machine. If it is not needed here, we should know. This package sound quite as if you should compile your file with LuaLaTeX. Just a guess.

Comment: @Gudrun did you remember to update MacTeX after you installed it? MacTeX is a yearly snapshot.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi apparently `gnuplot-lua-tikz.sty` is automatically generated by `gnuplot.lua` (I found it somewhere on my machine)

Comment: But I agree, without more information about the proper manner in which to get `gnuplot-lua-tikz.sty` and where exactly `\gpbboxborder` comes from, it is impossible to help. Not all of us are fluent in GNUPlot.

Comment: BTW: since the plot is generated by GNUPlot and its lua terminal, can we have the GNUPlot code and exact instructions on how to compile it with GNUPlot. Then I think we have a better chance of solving this.

Comment: `gnuplot-lua-tikz.sty` and friends are part of `gnuplot`. For example, it can be found in the sources of `gnuplot`. The example in the question runs without problems, when used with `gnuplot-lua-tikz.sty`  2014/11/09 (rev. 100) that comes with `gnuplot` 5.1. Maybe, the TeX compiler finds the wrong version.

Comment: @Heiko where exactly is that file? GNUPlot would problably not place it somewhere on a Mac that MacTeX can find by default.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I will try to answer your comments. 
Sorry, I meant tike.
I can publish my gnuplot example if you wish.
@daleif: I installed MacTeX yesterday from the MacTeX website. Is this not the newest version? Otherwise I would not know how to update it.

Comment: On my machine, the file would not be found by default because it is at `/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/gnuplot/gnuplot-lua-tikz.sty` which is not a standard TEXMF tree on my system. This can be fixed but I'm not sure where the file would end up on a Mac. I assume it would depend on the method you used to install GNUPlot.

Comment: It is true that I have in each of my folders a gnuplot-lua-tikz.sty. Somehow I copied it in all my folder where I create the Gnuplot graphs. 
What do you wish me now to do?

PS: Thanks for your nice welcomes! I do appreciate it.

Comment: I find gnuplot-lua-tikz.sty only in
/opt/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/gnuplot-lua-tikz/gnuplot-lua-tikz.sty
That is the path for the installation of TeXLive via Macports (but I remember it did not work as well in this version) 
I don't find something with the path for the installed version via MacTeX.

I meant tikz  above.

Comment: What does `gnuplot --version` give?

Comment: As I mentioned MacTeX is only made once a year. Any updates after the release has to be installed separately. Usually it suffices to run: `sudo tlmgr update --self --all` (if tlmgr is foudn under sudo).

Comment: Note that the copy of the sty file you have in all of your folders, might not be the latest version on your Mac (that would be the version that comes with GNUPlot).

Comment: gnuplot 5.0 patchlevel 1

Comment: I managed to create in a fresh (empty) folder with the following example a run that went through. 
I will enter the script above.. in my original post.

Comment: I think we solved it
The solution is : If one creates a new folder, it looks like a run is needed with set term tike standalone createstyle. This will create the right files in the folder for this gnuplot-lua thing. I did not know this. I always copied my old  gnuplot-lua-tikz.sty in the new folder.  Hence I had an old version in with the following text in "\ProvidesPackage{gnuplot-lua-tikz}%
          [2011/07/21 (rev. 100) GNUPLOT Lua terminal style]
"The new file has the following inside "\ProvidesPackage{gnuplot-lua-tikz}%
          [2014/11/09 (rev. 100) GNUPLOT Lua terminal style]"

Comment: But it seems true that "gnuplot-lua-tikz.sty" is not automatically found.

Answer (score 2):

The file `gnuplot-lua-tikz.sty` is automatically created in the directory where you run `gnuplot <file>` from, each time `gnuplot` is run. Its contents is fixed:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{gnuplot-lua-tikz}%
          [2014/11/09 (rev. 100) GNUPLOT Lua terminal style]

\RequirePackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,patterns,plotmarks,backgrounds,fit}
\input gnuplot-lua-tikz-common.tex

\endinput
```

and its accompanying file `gnuplot-lua-tikz-common.tex` is created each time as well (too long for being displayed here).

As far as I can see these files reside nowhere on the system, but are generated by a Lua script that I have in

```
/usr/local/Cellar/gnuplot/5.0.1/share/gnuplot/5.0/lua/gnuplot-tikz.lua
```

(corresponding on other systems to `/usr/local/share/gnuplot/...` or `/usr/share/gnuplot/...`).

If you want to make the generated `test_graph.plt.tex` file compilable, you *need* to have those generated files along with it.

It's possible that older versions of `gnuplot` provided “fixed” `gnuplot-lua-tikz.sty` and `gnuplot-lua-tikz-common.tex`, but the most recent one doesn't. I don't think it's good practice to save these files in some directory searchable by TeX (such as `$TEXMFHOME`), since the fact that they are generated every time seems to mean that the developers of `gnuplot` want to be free to update them without the need of interacting with TeX distributions.

Comment: Thank you. I don't think "The file gnuplot-lua-tikz.sty is automatically created in the directory where you run gnuplot <file> from, each time gnuplot is run." is for me the case. How could I check please?

Comment: I get the error ! LaTeX Error: File `gnuplot-lua-tikz.sty' not found.

Comment: My gnuplot was installed via MacPorts.

Comment: @Gudrun Do you have the file `gnuplot-tikz.lua` somewhere? And do you have Lua installed? By the way, I abandoned MacPorts years ago.

Comment: Yes, it is installed in /opt/local/share/gnuplot/5.0/lua/gnuplot-tikz.lua. I checked yesterday the ports, lua is installed.

Comment: In order to create style files in the working directory
automatically, the option createstyle is necessary:

`set out "test.tex"`
`set term lua tikz latex createstyle`
`plot sin(x)`

Alternatively one can install style files as

`tex/generic/gnuplot-lua-tikz/gnuplot-lua-tikz-common.tex`
`tex/latex/gnuplot-lua-tikz/gnuplot-lua-tikz.sty`
`tex/plain/gnuplot-lua-tikz/gnuplot-lua-tikz.tex`
`tex/context/third/gnuplot-lua-tikz/t-gnuplot-lua-tikz.tex`

where styles are obtained by a command:
`lua gnuplot-tikz.lua style`

Comment: You can simply generate the style files (like gnuplot-lua-tikz.sty) with one command in the commandline: `gnuplot -e 'set terminal tikz createstyle'`

Answer (score 2):

The error ocours because your pdflatex version doesn't know what to do with `\gpsetdashtype`. To avoid this you can edit `gnuplot-tikz.lua`, this file probably is in `/usr/share/gnuplot/gnuplot/5.0/lua/` or something like that. Change the line `gp.write("\\gpsetdashtype{"..dashtype.."}\n")` to `gp.write("$\\gpsetdashtype{"..dashtype.."}\n")`; this should do the trick. For safety make a copy before you any change. You can do something like

```
cd /usr/share/gnuplot/gnuplot/5.0/lua/
sudo cp gnuplot-tikz.lua gnuplot-tikz.lua.old
```

then

```
sudo sed -i "s/\\\\\\\\gpsetdashtype/%\\\\\\\\gpsetdashtype/" gnuplot-tikz.lua
```