# Creating an equally distributed multiplot with gnuplottex

Tags: gnuplot, gnuplottex

I'm tying to produce a vertical multiplot layout with `gnuplottex`. The different data sets it will contain share the same x axis and x range, so only the bottommost plot needs to have an x axis drawn. All other plots should then be positioned above with no margin between them, so that all plots look "connected".

Here is a minimal example that's producing *almost* what I want:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{gnuplottex}

\begin{document}

\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=cairolatex]

set multiplot layout 2,1
set tmargin 0
set bmargin 0

set key top left
set grid
set ylabel 'My y-label'
unset xlabel
set xtics format ""

plot sin(x) ls 1

set xlabel 'My x-label'
set xtics format "%f"
set bmargin 4

plot cos(x) ls 2

\end{gnuplot}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Unfortunately, this makes the bottommost plot have a lower height than the others due to the `set bmargin 4` before the second plot command.
If I remove `set bmargin 4`, both plots are equally sized, but the x-tics and -label are cut off:
[image]

Is there any way to get both, visible tics and equal sizes?

(This question is obviously more about `gnuplot` in general than `gnuplottex`. Please correct me if this is not the right place to ask this.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider switching to the tikz terminal:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[miktex]{gnuplottex}
\usepackage{gnuplot-lua-tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=tikz]

set multiplot layout 2,1
set tmargin 0
set bmargin 0

set key top left
set grid
set ylabel 'My y-label'
unset xlabel
set xtics format ""

plot sin(x) ls 1

set xlabel 'My x-label'
set xtics format "%f"

plot cos(x) ls 2

\end{gnuplot}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! :)

Just in case someone else has the following problem: when I first switched to tikz, I got a lot of `Undefined control sequence. [\gpsetdashtype]` errors. [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/368194/102821) fixed it for me.

Comment: on gnuplot 5.2 with `set terminal png, set output "gnuplot.png"`, this cuts off the lower tick labels and xlabel unfortunately.

Comment: @CiroSantilli新疆改造中心996ICU六四事件 Might be, but then you do not use the tikz terminal as suggested in the answer but the png terminal. The tikz terminal should generally be prefered due to it including the plot as a vector graphics, not as raster graphics.